# What is the word that is used to refer to a group of words used in specific vocations or specialized fields?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

An example would be words only used in a specialized field but not in daily life.  Or a word that has both a double meaning in daily use and in specialization.

Answer (score 1):

You have [*terminology* (Merriam-Webster):](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/terminology)

> **1 :**  the technical or special terms used in a business, art, science, or special subject

And you have [*Jargon* (Merriam-Webster):](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/jargon)

> **2 :**  the technical terminology or characteristic idiom of a special activity or group: sports *jargon*

Comment: Also ***lingo***

Answer (score 0):

Two words that come to mind are ***lexicon*** and, less formally ***jargon***.

One might talk, for example, about "dialysis" being part of *the medical lexicon*.

But a less formal term, such as "Monday flu" might be regarded as *doctors' jargon*, for someone who had had a heavy weekend and didn't much fancy turning up for work.